# Automapper en un método asíncrono?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Buen día estimados,

Estoy utilizando EFC en mi proyecto ASP.NET y tengo una duda respecto al automapper en un metodo asíncrono. A continuación les muestro este fragmento de código:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>> GetCompanies()
    {
        var usersInDb = await _context.Companies.ToListAsync();

        var usersInDto = _mapper.Map<CompanyDto>(usersInDb);

        return usersInDto ;
    }
```

Como ven lo que quiero es retornar esta api con el objeto CompanyDto ya mapeado pero me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrían ayudarme con esto?

De antemano muchas gracias...

Comment: El propio error te dice que tienes dos objetos diferentes, tal vez tengas que castearlo o necesites un método de conversión de los objetos

Comment: Efectivamente @NicolasOñate, se trataba de un tema de Casteo. El metodo me estaba generando un error al tratar de devolver un ActionResult.

Logré corregirlo de esta manera:

public async Task<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>> GetCompanies()
        {
            var usersInDb = await _context.Companies.ToListAsync();

            var usersInDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(usersInDb);

            return usersInDto;
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que tu Acción devuelve un objeto del tipo `IEnumerable<CompanyDto>`, y tu estás devolviendo un objeto simple del tipo `CompanyDto`.

Prueba a realizar el Mapeado pasándole como genérico un `IEnumerable<CompanyDto>`:

```
var usersInDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(usersInDb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se trataba de lo que el metodo retorna y las variables que estaban dentro del mismo.

Logré corregir el issue de la siguiente manera:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>> GetCompanies()
    {
        var usersInDb = await _context.Companies.ToListAsync();

        var usersInDto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyDto>>(usersInDb);

        return usersInDto;
    }
```

Con esto estoy devolviendo la lista de los objetos tipo Dto's y no de aquellos que interactuan con el DbContext. Y de manera asíncrona  :-)